# How to authorize my web api using mvc login from in .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-authorization

I have an MVC project and somewhere I must use AJAX call for performing some action. I have a login form which is working with MVC Controllers and create a session for authorization and create a cookie in client side for saving user login information. Now I want to prevent unauthorized user to call this web API method.

How can I share my login token between MVC controllers and WebAPI?

Comment: hope you can get some help from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Refer also [Authenticating Against Web API from ASP.NET MVC](http://www.csharpcity.com/2016/authenticating-against-web-api-from-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: I believe the question is way too broad. I suggest you to do some more research and try something by yourself first. Once you try something, you can ask here if it doesn't work as you expected and share the code you tried.

Comment: How did you solve this? I'm looking to do the same thing.